# How to generate test MS SQL geospatial data

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

I want to do some performance testing of a search algorithm on Geospatial data in SQL 2012.

What is the SQL command to generate X number of random data points with the following fields

1. Longitude double
2. Latitude double
3. Geography [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE NumberTable
  (
    number INT
  );

;WITH Numbers(number) AS
(SELECT 1 AS number
 UNION ALL
 SELECT number + 1 FROM Numbers WHERE number < 100
)
INSERT INTO NumberTable (number)
  SELECT N1.number + ((N2.number - 1) * 100)
    FROM Numbers N1, Numbers N2 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 100);

CREATE TABLE MyData 
  (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    longitude DECIMAL(7, 4),
    latitude DECIMAL(6, 4),
    location GEOGRAPHY
  );

INSERT INTO MyData (longitude, latitude)
  SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(8)) % 1800000 * 0.0001,
    CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(8)) % 900000 * 0.0001 FROM NumberTable WHERE number < 101;

UPDATE MyData
SET location =
      geography::STPointFromText(
        CONCAT('POINT (',
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), longitude),
               ' ',
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), latitude),
               ')'),
        4326)
WHERE location IS NULL;

SELECT
  id
  , longitude
  , latitude
  , location.STAsText() locationAsText
FROM MyData;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/528c2/2/0)

Beware of the "100"s and "101" currently limiting the number of generated records.

Please comment or extend your question if and as you see fit.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but can be useful to the thread visitors:

If you want to use T-SQL commands - that’s fine, but adopting the code to your needs may be very time-consuming. I suggest using some 3rd party tools for this purpose, and most of them have a fully functional free trial (like SQL test data generators from [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_generate.aspx) or [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)).

These tools can help you save lots of time, as they can create large volumes of data within a couple of clicks.